# SiteMapPath empty after upgrade to MVCSiteMap 4

Tags: mvcsitemapprovider

I just attempted to update the site map provider from 3.3.6.0 to 4.0.14. I followed the [instruction on the wiki](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Upgrading-from-v3-to-v4) however my SiteMapPath now renders empty. I made no changes to the mvc.sitemap file other than updating the schema to 4.0. When I debug into the SiteMapPathHelperModel I find that the model has no nodes defined. I am using the internal DI container (I would like to get this working before switching over to the application container).

When I check the sitemap.xml file it is well populated which makes me think that the mvc.sitemap is being read.

I'm out of ideas on this one and would be happy to provide any additional information which may be useful. I'm not even sure where I can hook into debug this problem. Literally the only thing I changed between a working 3.3.6.0 and a not working 4.0.14 was what was prescribed on the wiki.

Comment: Hey there. Did you ever get a solution to this? I just found myself in the same situation, and have no idea why the SiteMapPath() is blank

Answer (score 0):

Ok, since your `/sitemap.xml` endpoint appears to be working, you are correct the sitemap is being populated and loaded correctly.

There are a couple of things I know of that can cause this to happen:

1. If you are using Dynamic Node Providers, they must be added to a node that is not otherwise part of the sitemap. See [my question here](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/issues/210) - I am trying to figure out why this is the case as well.
2. Your routes don't match your nodes - please read [Routing Basics](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Routing-Basics) and/or post your routes and Mvc.sitemap XML.

If you check the above and everything appears to be correct, please make a small demo project showing a sample of your configuration and open an issue on GitHub, as it is highly likely your specific configuration has something to do with the problem.

BTW - You can debug by cloning the [current repo](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider) on your system or [downloading the solution as a zip](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/archive/master.zip), enabling NuGet package restore on your solution (right click the solution > Enable NuGet Package restore), add the MvcSiteMapProvider project to your solution, and then in your project remove the reference to MvcSiteMapProvider and add the reference to the newly added MvcSiteMapProvider project from your MVC project. Then you can add breakpoints and step through the code. I suggest making a backup of your solution (or ensure you can roll back another way) before doing this, and reverting back to your current state when done.

I have documented the whole procedure here: http://www.shiningtreasures.com/post/2013/08/21/debugging-an-mvcsitemapprovider-configuration